# android setup wizard downloading components error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation

I'm new On android studio. I Install last version of Android Studio and give the path of existing SDK folder path that I know they works on another PC of mine with android Studio.
but it wont start and on downloading component screen give me this error and exit.

```
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.
```

so after this message shown, setup closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with the help of a friend. 
The problem was with proxy and I need to set proxy mode in settings of android studio before running it.

The settings was:

You must find:

```
 C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio\config\options\others.xml
```

find **USE_PROXY_PAC** and then change value to "true". then turn on your proxy app and set the system to use proxy. and then run installer as **Administrator** and all components will install.